# Accessing Redux store in Constants file

Tags: react-native, redux

I am just beginning to grasp the concept of Redux, so this could be a rather silly question. 
I have a file that contains variables for my primary/accent colors.

> Colors.js

```
export default{
  primary: 'white',
  accent: 'black
}
```

I can successfully style my pages with Colors.primary and the like. However, I've created a boolean variable that I can toggle for a theme change via Redux. But I do not know what I need to do to this component in order to access this boolean and export different color schemes under primary/accent.

I feel like I've butchered this question, but I hope it has made at least a little bit of sense to some of you =P
Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've learned that refreshing StyleSheet seems to be a hassle. I've found a very tedious workaround by creating different StyleSheets for each theme and using inline if-statements to point to the desired style. 

This works for now, but if there is a less-redundant approach then please let me know =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following approach.

1. Redux is used for storing state. It stores either boolean  variable which will select style in use or style itself.
2. Constants file `Colors.js` is used for defining themes (and maybe other styles) and imported to file, which contains Redux reducers.

For example

```
// store/themes.js
import Colors from Colors.js
const TOGGLE_COLOR= "TOGGLE_COLOR"

export const actionCreators = {
    ToggleColor:() => ({ type: TOGGLE_COLOR })
}

export const initalThemeState = {
    color: Colors.primary
    // Here can be other theme variables
}



export const reducer = (state = initalThemeState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_COLOR:
            return {
                ...state,
                color: state.color === Colors.primary ? Colors.accent : Colors.primary  // This line actually changes color in response to 
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And component which will display UI for theme toggling

```
export const ColorToggle = ({ ToggleColor }) => (
  <Button onPress={ToggleColor} title='Toggle color' />
);

export default connect(
  null,
  actionCreators
)(ColorToggle);
```

And another component, which will display content based on currently selected theme color

```
import Colors from './Colors.js'

export const ColoredText = ({ color }) => (
  <Text style={{ backgroundColor: color, color: "green" }}>Colored div</Text>
);

export default connect(
  state => state.theme,
  null
)(ColoredText);
```

And here is [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/styledtext-orvi7)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I'm working with react-native, so I'll have to play around a bit to see if I can get this to work for me =P

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed that you're using React-Native. But everything will work in React-Native too. I've modified my code for React-Native and also adopted demo.

Comment: Much appreciated! I've upvoted your comment, but I don't have the necessary reputation to make that action public =P